# Ruby on Rails: Is there anything similar to C++ virtual methods for subclasses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I've got an abstract model that has a lot of implementing submodels. I'd like to be able to define some functions in the abstract model that rely on the submodel's own definitions when called on the submodel. Is such a thing possible in Ruby on Rails?

Example, where the length attributes are defined in the submodels:

```
class Animal
  validates_inclusion_of :length, :in => MIN_LENGTH..MAX_LENGTH
end

class Elephant < Animal
  MIN_LENGTH = 5
  MAX_LENGTH = 20
end
```

Then when I go to Elephant.new.save! I'd like it to run the validation with Elephant's constants.

The reason I want to do this is because the fact that there will be such validations is going to be universal to all of the submodels, the only thing that varies is the value of the constants.

When I tried to do it like this, or with lower-cased methods, in both cases I get a name error for the undefined values.

Is such a thing possible in Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
validates_inclusion_of :length, :in => MIN_LENGTH..MAX_LENGTH
```

gets executed when Ruby sees your Animal class. So, it's naturally it uses the values of `MIN/MAX_LENGTH` as they appear at that time. To override this behavior you can do this:

```
validates_inclusion_of :length, :in => lambda {|animal| animal.class.age_range }
```

Then define in both your `Animal` and `Elephant` classes (or just in the last one if you don't plan to "gave birth" to a "just `Animal`"):

```
def self.age_range
  # < some suitable range, like 5..20 >
end
```

This way your range for `:in` will be calculated when it is needed, providing `:in` with a suitable range for some species.

P.S. I guess you omitted the base class for your `Animal` just to save few keystrokes ;)

Comment: Are you certain this works? It definitely sounds like a great idea to me. However, Rails seems to be expecting :in to point to a container rather than passing in the animal to my lambda function. This is the error I'm getting - ArgumentError: An object with the method include? is required must be supplied as the :in option of the configuration hash

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Heres's excerpt from API docs: `validates_inclusion_of :states, :in => lambda{ |person| STATES[person.country] }`. Moreover, I tested it before answering.

Comment: Ah, figured it out. Looks like this was added on Apr 10, 2011, which probably means I need to move on to at least Rails 3.1 from 3.0 for this to work.

Comment: Sorry about that. You neglected to specify the versions of your software so I couldn't be more helpful.